# Override prop on component instance in React

Tags: reactjs

If a component has an existing prop being passed to it, how can I override this in a HOC. The following will display `bar` and not `changed`, which makes sense from an application standpoint.

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        {this.props.foo}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App2 = props => <App {...props} foo={"bar"} />;
const App3 = props => <App2 {...props} foo={"changed"} />;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App3 />, rootElement);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/k015wplr6o

This is part of a larger application where an instance of a component is stored, and later the instance must be recreated with a different value as a prop.

Comment: Why not `const App2 = props => <><App {...props} foo={"bar"} /><App {...props} foo={"changed"} /></>;`?

Comment: change the order of `{...props}` and `foo={"bar"}`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Thanks! I had tried changed the order on `App3`, but changing them on `App2` did it!

Comment: Changing was indeed needed in App2 component

Comment: i have face something similar, i have a component  lets say child  which accepts props like testprops, which is used in other two components firstcomponent and second component , both of them called in mainpage, so the testprops of  child component are different for first and second component but second component props get override on the firstcomponent child testprops. can someone help me in this. thanks